# Mongoid "no geo index :(" error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid, ruby-on-rails-4

Steps to reproduce:

```
class Venue
  field :coordinates, type: Array
  index({coordinates: '2d'}, {min: -180, max: 180})
end
```

Have ran rake db:mongoid:create_indexes

Tried calling:

```
Venue.geo_near([@lat, @long])
```

And got:

```
Moped::Errors::OperationFailure:
   The operation: #<Moped::Protocol::Command
     @length=135
     @request_id=3
     @response_to=0
     @op_code=2004
     @flags=[]
     @full_collection_name="encore_backend_test.$cmd"
     @skip=0
     @limit=-1
     @selector={:geoNear=>"venues", :near=>[43.670906, -79.393331], :query=>{}, :spherical=>true}
     @fields=nil>
   failed with error "no geo index :("
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: You do have lat and long the wrong way around in ```Venue.geo_near([@lat, @long])``` and also in your error dump. Please consider using the 2dsphere index instead, as it implements a true spherical geo index too.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Stupid mistake, forgot to do rake `db:mongoid:create_indexes` with `RAILS_ENV=test` for RSpec

Complete command

```
bundle exec rake db:mongoid:create_indexes RAILS_ENV=test
```

Comment: Thanks for asking and replying man. I didn't even know i had to do that. Is that set somewhere in mongoid's docs?